# How do I capture video from my laptop's camera using C#

Tags: c#, multimedia

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to capture video from my laptop's camera using C#. I found some info at MSDN **VideoCaptureDevices** and **CaptureSource**. Also I added **windowsbase.dll** into my references.  The above class and methods I'm not able to use.

How can the above classes be used without using Silverlight concepts?

Answer (score 1):

`windowsbase.dll` is part of Windows Presentation Foundation (which has a lot of overlap with Silverlight). To use types from `windowsbase.dll` you'll need a WPF application (with all the learning curve if you don't know any WPF).

If you want a GUI application then WPF is a good approach.

(Otherwise: please update the question with more context.)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your response. You mean we cant use inbuilt functions in C#.net inorder to capture video from webcam? Also is C# application very different from WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of Silverlight, the Microsoft Expression Encoder SDK might do the job.
In fact it has another API to communicate to devices.

Comment: hi ba_friend, i dont want to use any other SDKs but whatever the in built functions under System.Windows.Media inorder to capture video from a webcam i want to use them. is there any solution for this?

Comment: It looks like it is a Silverlight-only API. So there might be no possible way to use this without Silverlight.